# D365 Open a different Form depending on a field-value in UCI (eg: Contact Type)

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-uci

In using the new UCI interface with Dynamics 365.
Within Contacts, I have two saved views: "Supplier Contacts" and "Client Contacts".
This hinges on a "Contact Type" of either (you guessed it) Supplier or Client.

Each has a distinct way in which I want to view the form - there are some relationsips shown in subgrids and fields that apply uniquely to the respective Contact Type.  **Therefore, I want to show two different forms depending on the Contact Type.**

Is this possible firstly without Javascript?  If Javascript is required, how do I make sure it loads and flicks to the correct form type without flickering and being too much of an annoyance to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible without JavaScript.

Multiple forms & form switcher are for showing different form to different user base, it’s security role driven. Last visited form will be remembered & rendered if user has access to multiple forms.

We can do form scripting to switch it based on need. If the form layout is complex like too many subgrids/section/controls to show/hide then form switcher is the way. UX is bad I agree, you cannot circumvent this. There is no form init or preload kinda events in Dynamics CRM Product.

If the form layout is simple to handle by grouping controls in **sections** in turn in a **tab** then show/hide the entire tab based on field value. This is better option. But maintenance nightmare may result.